# Wrong attribute set ID Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, install-script

I have been receiving this error.

Error:

> mysql4-install-1.0.php" - Wrong attribute set ID";i:1;s:1016:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flicdes/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')

Code:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->load();
foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $id => $attributeSet) {
    $setup->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName(), 'Product Brand', 1000);
}
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', array(
    'group' => 'Product Brand',
    'label' => 'MGS Brand',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'frontend_class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique' => false
));
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_filterable', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_filterable_in_search', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_visible_on_front', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'used_in_product_listing', 0);
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand')} (
  `entity_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_featured` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `number_of_products` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`url_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand_products')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand_products')} (
  `entity_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `entity_id` with `id` So:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->load();
foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $id => $attributeSet) {
    $setup->addAttributeGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName(), 'Product Brand', 1000);
}
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', array(
    'group' => 'Product Brand',
    'label' => 'MGS Brand',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    'frontend_class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
    'unique' => false
));
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_filterable', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_filterable_in_search', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'is_visible_on_front', 0);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'mgs_brand', 'used_in_product_listing', 0);
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_featured` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `number_of_products` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`url_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand_products')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('mgs_brand_products')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I have got the same error.

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:139:"Error in file: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flicdes/app/code/local/MGS/Brand/sql/brand_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.php" - Wrong attribute set ID";i:1;s:1016:"#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flicdes/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/flicdes/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.1')

Comment: Did you changed your `AttributeSet` ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I changed all words 'entity_id' for 'id', and got the same error.

Comment: Magento version: 1.9.3.8

Comment: PHP : 5.6.30   and MySql: 5.6.35

Comment: What is the name of the attribute set of catalog product ? you can check that in admin when you create an product attribute